# Как получать данные полей формы,созданной на ReactJs и Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Пытаюсь написать форму, в которой есть компоненты material ui. С помощью get-запроса jquery  я научился получать данные с бекэнда и выводить их(например в список autocomple по клику пользователя),но появилась другая проблема. Вот пользователь выбрал из списка какоу-то значение и нажал кнопку "от отправить". Как в react'e происходит считывание данных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правило, у элемента ввода по событию `onChange(event)` отлавливают введенное значение (`event.target.value`) и сохраняют в `this.state`. А уже при отправке формы пользуются значением из `this.state`. Но есть и другой вариант: полю ввода назначить атрибут `ref`, присвоив какое-нибудь значение, например `myInput`. Далее при отправке формы, используя доступ к полю через `this.refs.myInput`, получают значение и формируют запрос на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте ReduxForm, по мне, так очень удобно.

TextField:

```
import React from "react";
import fp from "lodash/fp";
import { bool, func, node, number, object, string } from "prop-types";
import { Field } from "redux-form";
import { TextField } from "material-ui";

TextFieldComponent.propTypes = {
  meta: object,
  input: object,
  parseOnBlur: func
};
TextFieldComponent.defaultProps = { parseOnBlur: fp.identity };

export function TextFieldComponent({ input, meta, parseOnBlur, ...custom }) {
  return (
    <TextField
      {...input}
      {...custom}
      errorText={!meta.active && meta.touched && meta.error}
      onBlur={fp.flow(fp.get("target.value"), parseOnBlur, input.onBlur)}
    />
  );
}

FormTextField.propTypes = {
  parse: func,
  format: func,
  validate: func,
  parseOnBlur: func,
  name: string.isRequired,

  type: string,
  readOnly: bool,
  disabled: bool,

  fullWidth: bool,
  multiLine: bool,

  hintText: node,
  floatingLabelText: node,
  rows: number,
  rowsMax: number
};

export default function FormTextField(props) {
  return <Field {...props} component={TextFieldComponent} />;
}
```

Форма:

```
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { FlatButton } from "material-ui";
import { object } from "prop-types";

const enhancer = reduxForm({
  form: "form"
})

FormComponent.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: object
}

function FormComponent(props) {
  return(
    <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
      <FormTextField name="name" floatingLabelText="User Name" />
      <FlatButton type="submit" label="Submit" />
    </form>
  )
}

export default enhancer(FormComponent);
```

Container:

```
function FormContainer() {
  return(
    <FormComponent
      onSubmit={values => apiMethod(values)}
    />
  )
}

export default FormContainer;
```

[reduxForm](http://redux-form.com/) - Официальная документация